# Awaitility: how to perform post-actions if a condition failed?

Tags: java, awaitility

In Awaitility, how can I perform a post-action if a condition I'm waiting for fails? For example, collecting additional information, do some logging, or throwing an exception?

The only way I've found is to use a `try-catch`:

```java
try {
  Awaitility.await().until(myCondition)
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // post actions
}
```

Is there a more Awaitility-like way of doing this?

Comment: You should catch `ConditionTimeoutException`, not just any exception. Also, be aware that if you catch the exception, your test will not fail. So you may therefore want to re-throw the exception.

Comment: @k314159 well, that's exactly what I asked in the question - the only solution I found is `try-catch`, but I'm looking (if any) for a more Awaitility-native approach to do so. Yes, I'm aware that it throws `ConditionTimeoutException`. I used `Exception` type in my code snippet just for simplicity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [condition evaluation listener](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#condition-evaluation-listener):

```
await()
        .conditionEvaluationListener(condition -> {
            if (condition.getRemainingTimeInMS() <= 0) {
                // Do stuff!
            }
        })
        .until(myCondition)
```